# Debugger is not hitting for multiple project solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

I have three projects:

1. Web Project(MVC)
2. API Project
3. C# Project

API project if called from Web project and C# project called from API project. I am debugging a web application as start up project and given break point for a method in C# project. Debugger is not hitting in C# project. But debugger is working in web project. I am not able to get the solution
Please help me to get resolved

Comment: Did you just start one of them? You can attach the debugger to additional applications via the "Debug"/"Attach to process" command in the VS menu.

Comment: When you set the breakpoint on the C# project, does it look like a full red circle or is it hollow? If you hover over the breakpoint, does a tooltip come up? What does it say?

Comment: Yes i am getting red circle in C# project, hollow in API project and it says the break point will not currently be hit..

Comment: There is your problem. Stop the debugger and recompile the solution, then start again. See if that helps.

Comment: I have tried many times, Its not working

Comment: First make sure you use the "Clean Solution" option of the Build menu. Sometimes stuff gets a hold of your files and the compiler fails silently. After cleaning the solution, try again. What configuration are you using? Debug? Go into the Configuration Manager window and make sure the projects are set to use the Debug configuration and that the Build checkmark is set.

Comment: Check the Output window when compiling too. See if it gives you any errors about not being able to build.

Comment: I have tried with multiple startup project,, I have selected all three projects. Now its working fine. Thank you for your valuable time guys